# Hibernate Upgrade from 3 to 4.3.5

Tags: java, hibernate, upgrade

while upgrading hibernate from 3 to 4, After replacing the .jar files and replacing some of the depreciated method with the new one some packages are giving following errors:

```
 1. error: package org.hibernate.impl does not exist
    [javac] import org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl;
 2. error: package org.hibernate.impl does not exist
    [javac] import org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl;
 3. error: package org.hibernate.jmx does not exist
    [javac] import org.hibernate.jmx.StatisticsService;
```

Why this error coming ? Are these packages are also depreciated in the hibernate 4.3.5. ?

Pls Suggest.Thanks.

Comment: This package doesn't exist anymore, as [the javadoc](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/javadocs/) shows. These classes are now in org.hibernate.internal (as the javadoc also shows). Your code should not rely on these classes anyway, which are internal to Hibernate, but on their public interface: Session and SessionFactory.

Comment: @JBNizet: Thanks. This was really helpful. Do you have any idea on import org.hibernate.jmx.StatisticsService; Package. If yes please mention your comment with the previous comment as an answer.I also updated the question.